# How do I install Huawei E5372 USB dongle on 12.04

Tags: software-installation, usb-modem, huawei

I just got a new USB modem **huawei E5372**, can someone please put me through or point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu have most huawei dongles drives. One you plugged it Mobile connection will show up, click on it and follow the steps.

Comment: For me it didn't. said unable to mount.

Comment: Doesn't need additional driver installations. Open a Terminal  By Pressing Ctrl + Alt + T . Then copy this command and paste it in the Terminal and Press enter. Follow through the Installation Process. At the end you will find an application called Modem Manager Gui in the dash. `sudo apt-get install modemmanager modem-manager-gui`

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install usb_modeswitch
```

Make sure the huawei dongle is in the right mode with `lsusb`, should be device-id 1506 (if your unfamiliar with this read some info about internet sticks+linux+usb_modeswitch)

Now doing `ifconfig` should show you an interface `wwan0`, this is your dongle. You don't need to dial in or anything, just simply request an IP-address with:

```
sudo ip link set wwan0 up
```

Possibly you also have to call dhclient but for me the above was enough.

```
sudo dhclient wwan0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing and configuring `wvdial`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here.